# Is it wise to use triggers as part of an import routine

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, import, triggers

Hi all I have a requirement to create a web based application using SQL server 2005. The data is coming from a third party source in a text format. This is my idea so far.

1. I have a file system watcher looking for a file in a directory
2. I loop through the file found, find the columns and insert the data one by one in a table
3. Once all data has been inserted, run a stored procedure against the table to do some more cleaning and create totals used within the web app

As you can see there are mainly 2 steps involved within the import after the file has been found. Those are storing data in SQL server and the second to clear up values and do some other work within my database. My question is if as I am looping through the values anyway can I have a trigger (and yes I do know that a trigger is per execution not for every row) to do the cleaning for me as I insert the records in my table.

For example I loop through one by one figure out the columns and then insert them into the table. As that happens a trigger is fired to runs some script (possibly stored procedures)to do some other work on other tables. That way all my file system watch needs to do is get the data and insert them into the table. The trigger will do all the other work. Is this advisable and what will happen if a trigger is already running a script and it is called again by another insert to the table?

Sorry for the long question

Thanks

Comment: Triggers introduce side-effects which are hard to test and debug.  Best to do things explicitly.

Comment: Also, performace-wise you'll be better off without the triggers.